# How do I configure my Start Menu to display 6 medium tile columns?

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, live-tiles

I know how to change my start menu between 3 and 4 medium tile columns.

I know how to maximize my start menu.

Recently I've seen newer users of Windows 10 who's default, unmaximized Start Menu shows 2 groups of 3 columns of medium tiles side by side.

Can anyone describe what settings might control this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to **Settings** > **Personalization** > **Start**
Toggle the switch for "Show more tiles."
Turning it off sets the start menu groups to 3 medium tiles per column. Drag the menu itself to resize and change the number of columns.